# How to install PDO driver for PHP 7.1 on windows

Tags: php, file, web, download

After trying to find my php.ini file (which I still cannot find), I realised while using `phpinfo();` that I have no PDO drivers. Is there any way I can solve both of the problems?

I have found php.ini-production and php.ini-development. Both look exactly the same, how do I enable the extensions as I believe that is what I'm supposed to do?

Comment: When you run phpinfo(), can't you find your .ini file at the configuration file path?

Comment: It just says "C:\WINDOWS"

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the next field down should give you the config file that was loaded. What does the next field down say? It might say something like C:\WINDOWS\php.ini-production...

Comment: The field is "Loaded Configuration File" and beside it, it says "(none)"

Comment: Did you restart your http server after you installed PHP? In the Linux world, I can recreate that if I don't restart Apache after. Also, is there a php.ini file at C:\WINDOWS?

Comment: I'm sorry as this will sound stupid, but what is apache. I have installed php 7.1 and mysql workbench. Using windows 10

Comment: It doesn't sound stupid, though it certainly makes this issue more complicated. The simplest possible answer is that Apache is an http server - it is responsible for making sure that you load the right web page at the desired time. Have you ever considered using something like XAMPP? It will install php/Apache/mysql and some tools for you.

Comment: Have installed it now and am seeing this error "Problem detected!
22:19:15  [mysql]  Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" MySQL57"! 
22:19:15  [mysql]  MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free! 
22:19:15  [mysql]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application 
22:19:15  [mysql]  or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port"

Comment: That error is telling you that you have mysql running twice. Either uninstall the first one you installed (considering your technical ability, this is likely the best choice) or shut down that service.

Comment: I only have one version installed, it seems to want to use the same port as my phpstorm is using. Is that the problem?

Comment: PHPstorm is an IDE. It is not the problem here. Keep in mind that XAMPP installs php/Apache and mySql. The error message you posted shows that port 3306 is being used by both C:\Program Files\MySQL and the MySQL implementation that ships with XAMPP.

Comment: I believe I am so far off course, as I only originally needed to install a PDO driver and believe that's still the problem. XAMPP seems like a useful tool for someone who knows what they're doing. I'm just trying to install the pdp_mysql extension. You have been incredibly helpful though, thank you!

Comment: Seriously, I can't believe that you'd waste my time like that. You said you couldn't find your php.ini file, then showed that you literally do not have a clue...

Comment: Exactly dude, I feel like my taking on XAMPP I'm just adding to my problems, am I not?

Comment: No, you are wrong. You don't know what an http server is and frankly, you seem to be having some really huge issues following instructions setting up your WAMP stack. XAMPP is built for people like you. That said, I have wasted way more time than I am willing to give. Good luck.